# Android Game Crash On Unity Ads

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, cocos2d-x, ads

> Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.unity3d.services.core.configuration.IExperiments com.unity3d.services.core.configuration.Configuration.getExperiments()' on a null object reference
> at com.unity3d.services.ads.operation.load.LoadModuleDecoratorTimeout. (LoadModuleDecoratorTimeout.java:25)
> at com.unity3d.services.ads.operation.load.LoadModule.getInstance (LoadModule.java:35)
> at com.unity3d.services.ads.UnityAdsImplementation.load (UnityAdsImplementation.java:171)
> at com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds.load (UnityAds.java:281)
> at com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds.load (UnityAds.java:261)
> at org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity$18.run (AppActivity.java:728)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6977)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:528)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:910)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.